# Rails undefined method in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have model named `TMem`:

```
class TMem < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
   def expense
      'Test'
   end 
end
```

When I try to execute the command in `rails c`:

```
TMem.find(1).expense
```

I got the error :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `expense' for #<TMem:0xb5fb97c>
```

Why I got this error?

Comment: Did you restart your console after implementing `TMem#expense` method?

Comment: Or just execute `reload!` from console.

Comment: Oh.I am careless,It work now,just restart my console ,thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should restart your console after defining a new method in Rails model

or just perform reload using `reload!`

`reload!` only reloads the latest code in the console environment. It does not re-initialize existing objects. Means if you have any objects already created it would not update its attributes on code change, but if you create a new object it will work for new attributes